# Multi GP gate sizes

Tags: quadcopters, multirotor

Multi GP Gate sizes are given in square inch/ft like so: 25 sq ft  (5’x5’ – 1.52m x 1.52m) - those are obviously the size requirements for a square gate. If I want to have a "Multi GP compliant" gate which is round, should I build one with the diameter being the length of a side or should I match the area of the square gate?

Or will a round gate never be "Multi GP compliant" anyways?

Comment: Huh... good question! I mean, I think only the race gates MultiGP sells are legal by them, but I don't know for sure. "Compliance" is a loose requirement, lol... you could really quantify it either way, by diameter or open area.